# Different globbing behavior with same shopts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, globbing

I have multiple shells (bash) open on the same machine, and in one of them, globbing seems to have stopped. `ls *` gives `ls: *: No such file or directory`, and so on. I figured that I must have set some glob options by mistake, but `shopt | grep glob` gives

```
dotglob         off
extglob         off
failglob        off
nocaseglob      off
nullglob        off
```

the same as in my other shells. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If your current directory is empty, the `*` pattern will not match anything. In this case, since `nullglob` is off, the `*` string is **not** replaced and you're asking `ls` to list the file named `"*"`. If you want the pattern to be replaced by an empty string when it does not match anything, use `shopt -s nullglob`

Comment: The directory has files in it. I'm seeing this behavior with '*' expansion in every directory in this shell.

Comment: `unset GLOBIGNORE`?

Comment: @Cyrus tired `unset GLOBIGNORE`, still the same

Comment: What is "ls"? Do `type -a ls`

Comment: `set +f` to reenable globbing?